# Trouble running package "xlsx"

Tags: r, runtime-error, xlsx

After installing R and RStudio on my new computer everything works fine, except the "xlsx" package. When trying to call it with `library(xlsx)` I get this error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

The `version`command produces the following output:

```
> version
           _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

I see from similar questions that this problem might stem from the fact that the Java and the R versions don't correspond. But here, everything else works, and so far this seems to be the only package that produces this error message. I can't have more than one Java version installed at the time, can I? I have tried to reinstall the package, with the same result.

I have quite a lot of scripts where I have used the "xlsx" package, the synthax is different than the alternative package "readxl" and I would by far prefer to make the "xlsx" package work, rather than switching to "readxl". The "xlsx" package also comes with more options.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the `read_excel()` function from the `readxl` package instead

Comment: your Java and R should be of the same arch for `xlsx` to work.

Comment: How do I achieve that? I have installed a 64-bit Java...

Comment: I installed both 32- and 64-bit Java and it worked. Thank you for putting me on the right track.